# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: is displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My HTML code is

```
  <a class="ui-btn-right close-btn ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-rel="back" href="#" role="button"></a>
```

Selinum code is

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-btn-right.close-btn.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-btn-a.ui-icon-delete.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all")).click();
```

Exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
```

Comment: Even tried driver.findElement(By.className(".ui-btn-right.close-btn.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-btn-a.ui-icon-delete.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all")).click();

Comment: For all compound className i am getting this error message

Comment: Error is  pretty clear. By the time you are clicking, the element is not attached to the DOM.

Comment: Do i need to increase to sleep time, i am using 2000 as sleep time

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not a selenium guy :) Just by reading error message. What I understood is the element is not attached to DOM (may be display none or removed).

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript executor.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-btn-right.close-btn.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-btn-a.ui-icon-delete.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all"));

((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

If this does'nt work use the following code to make the element (not recommended)

```
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibilty = 'visible'", element)
```